# SPANタグの TITLE属性で表示される ToolTipのフォントサイズを変更したいです

Tags: css

SPANタグに TITLE属性を付けておくとマウスオーバーで ToolTipが表示されます。
このとき、表示されるフォントのサイズが少し小さくなるので、これを元の文字と同じサイズで表示したいのですが、どのようなCSSを記述すればよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ブラウザの標準の機能を使ったツールチップは恐らく変更できません。
Javascriptを利用したツールチップを利用します。
英語サイトですが、簡単なものはjQueryというライブラリを使ったものがあります。

http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

ご参考まで。

Comment: すばやいご回答、ありがとうございました。

やはりブラウザ標準のツールチップは変更できませんか。

jQueryや独自のライブラリでカスタマイズしたツールチップを実装できるのは分かっているのですが、Firefox用の拡張機能 "Gmail Subject Popupper" https://addons.mozilla.org/ja/firefox/addon/gmail-subject-popupper/ を作ったときに手っ取り早く Title属性を利用したので、このままでツールチップをカスタマイズできたらいいなと思っていたのですが、、、

Comment: @backy0175 title属性は"Values of the title attribute may be rendered by user agents"と定義されて、その挙動はブラウザの実装に一任されています（大体はツールチップだろうとも書かれていますが）。なのでCSS側でどうこうできないのです。 CSSだけで何とかする方法はhoverトリックがありますが。width固定だったり。固定をやめたら文字が1単語ごとに改行されてしまったりと使いにくいのです)。

一応、(個人的には)ネタとして http://downloads.sixrevisions.com/css-tooltips/index.html 紹介しておきますね。

Comment: @backy0175 jQueryなら、 obj.attr("title") 等でタイトル属性も取得できますから、探せばあると思います。

Comment: @NorikazIshii 情報ありがとうございます。とりあえず Firefoxの標準ツールチップをカスタマイズするCSSが userstyles.org にありました。 https://userstyles.org/styles/36/change-tooltip-colors-and-fonts 
このCSSでカスタマイズすると Firefox全体のツールチップがカスタマイズされてしまいますので、拡張機能の補足情報として紹介して、このあたりの運用はユーザーさんの判断に任せたいと思います。
(後で、標準ツールチップのフォントサイズだけ変更する userstyleを登録しておきます)

Comment: @Monon 情報ありがとうございます。Gmailとの兼ね合いがあるのでこれからどう対応していくか検討してみます。

Comment: Firefoxの標準ツールチップのフォントサイズを変更できる userstyleを登録しました。
"Customize font size for Firefox defalt tooltip " https://userstyles.org/styles/111127/customize-font-size-for-firefox-defalt-tooltip